# Word Press Form Submission (Forminator) Data Truncated

Tags: php, wordpress

Given the following code, using Forminator Pro, I'm seeing submissions that are truncated.

My first attempt was to send JSON data, but the buffer that I received had many null bytes at the end of it, after around 16k of data.

I stepped back from JSON and simply attempted to send the data as serialized text directly from the array, just to see if all of the data was in the array, or if the json encode was the issue. Again, only around 16k arrived.

The form that I'm using is fairly large.

Is there some configuration option to increase the size of some buffer somewhere?

What about the particular hook? Instead of `forminator_custom_form_submit_before_set_fields` is there some other hook that might produce all of the form data?

What about an API to grab the individual form field names and values directly from the database so I can build the post data?

```
add_action('forminator_custom_form_submit_before_set_fields', 'form_post_json', 10, 3);

function form_post_json($entry, $form_id, $form_data_array) {
    $postform = 123;
    $postto = 'https://example.com';

    if (intval($form_id) === $postform) {
        // $jsondata = json_encode($form_data_array); // JSON attempt
        $serialized = serialize($form_data_array);
        $postdata = [
            'method'      => 'POST',
            'timeout'     => 60,
            'httpversion' => '1.1',
            'blocking'    => false,
            'headers'     => [
                // 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', // JSON attempt
                'Content-Type' => 'text/plain',
                'Expect' => '',
            ],
            'sslverify'   => true,
            // 'body'        => $jsondata, // JSON attempt
            'body'        => $serialized,
            'data_format' => 'body',
        ];
        $response = wp_remote_post($postto, $postdata);
}
```

Comment: Check post_max_size and upload_max_filesize, these settings in php.ini determine the maximum size of POST data and uploaded files. If your form data exceeds these limits, it could be truncated.

Comment: What exactly is truncated here - the data the above code receives as its input already; or just what gets received at the "other end" of `$response = wp_remote_post($postto, $postdata);` ?